# How can I send only .php files to same page?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I would like to have url's like this

```
mysite.com/language/page/somethingelse
```

And processing that always in the same file which is `index.php`.

But only for `.php` files. I don't want to redirect `.js` or `.css` or `.xml`, image files and so on.

Plus, this project will be in a subfolder, meaning it will be inside another with no relation whatsoever. Therefore, it will be accessible like this:

```
mysite.com/extras/mydifferentproject/language/page/something else
```

So I suppose the `.htaccess` file inside `mydifferentproject` folder will need this line?

```
RewriteBase extras/mydifferentproject/
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have this as a `.htacces`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(?!index\.php$). index.php [NS,L,DPI]
```

---

#### Catching the value after the folder

From the folder that the `.htacces` is in all the `URL's` will be caught. In order to get the path and get if it's in a folder and process it further this function will help.

```
function getPath($path){
    $called = __FILE__;
    $called_dir = str_replace("\\","/",pathinfo($called)["dirname"]);
    $root = str_replace($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"], "",$called_dir);
    $from = '/'.preg_quote($root, '/').'/';
    return preg_replace($from,"",$path,1);
}
```

---

#### How to use

```
getPath($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
```

This will get you the string that is behind the folder it is in, so it excludes the folder it is in.

---

#### Example

**.htacces**: is in the folder `/folder`
**url**: `example.com/folder/some/values`
***result*** of the `getPath()` function in `index.php` **:** `/some/values` as it's in the folder `folder`.

---

#### Not in folder

In the case that your URL `example.com/index.html` is, but the `.htacces` is in `folder` the behavior is just normal. *(will load index.html)*

---

### Important

When loading files through a process of handeling the path, or anything you do with it. When loading requesting files in the `html` be sure to define the `base` of where he files should be loaded from, otherwise it will take the `path` input from above and see those as folders, and not as values or something it should not look at.

*Example*

```
<base href="/folder/">
```

Comment: I create the .htaccess file with your code. But is sending .js files to index.php too.

Comment: Yes, anything you put from the the folder up where the `.htacces` is will be caught and send you to the `index.php`. How and why do you want `.js` endings to not be send to the `index.php`?

Comment: I would like to redirect only ``.php`` files. If the browser request images, js files, xml files etc, I don't want redirection.

Comment: It might be worth adding a white list of "allowed" pages to prevent any potential LFI vulnerabilities.

Comment: @Darren Is there a way Nytrix's ``RewriteRule`` can be modified so it only affect ``.php`` files?

Comment: @user2755140 *But*... In your example, you don't have the `.php` extension, that get's hard all of the sudden, when you on the one hand want to catch everything and but then also only one thing?

Comment: It seems you missed where it says (and I'm copy/pasting): **But only for .php files. I don't want to redirect .js or .css or .xml, image files and so on.**

Comment: I like your code. I just need it to work only for ``.php`` files. Your answer is good.

Answer (score 0):

I could accomplish the following task **send only `.php` files to index.php** like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA]
```

Now I'm able to access images and js, css, xml files, etc, by writing their real url's in the browser's navbar.

Once in **index.php** I'm using Nytrix's function to parse the url.