# PHP avoid direct access to internal php files in public folder

Tags: php

I'm redirecting to the same page `index.php` via `.htaccess` everything that looks like this:

```
mysite.com/something/somethingelse/blahblah
```

Which means: url's that don't exist. That way, requests like

```
mysite.com/includes/js/script.js
```

Are still accessible.

But I would like to avoid access this way:

```
mysite.com/includes/php/dostuff.php
```

So I would like to know if there is a method I could use to check in `dostuff.php` that the file is being accessed directly and not via `require`.

What I have thought so far is to check `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`. But I'm a little lost about what to do from there.

Comment: Please refer to the answer I gave here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41667483/how-can-i-send-only-php-files-to-same-page . Oh yes, it's you again! In my *final* answer there, this problem is already solved. It has to do with the `<base>` tag, look for the **important** header in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

add a .htaccess to the php directory with:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
```

Answer (score -2):

I think it can be done easily checking if a variable exists. So in `dostuff.php` and similar files there will be this line at the top:

```
if(empty($myvar)) exit;
```

However, that won't work on internal files called via **ajax**. So I still need help to figure out that.